# iconv converting latin to utf

Tags: php, iconv

```
function convertStringUtf8 ($s)
{

    file_put_contents ( '/tmp/utf8_param' , $s);
    file_put_contents ( '/tmp/utf8_mbdetect' , mb_detect_encoding($s));
    file_put_contents ( '/tmp/utf8_other' , iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', "Á"));
    if (function_exists('iconv'))
          {
            file_put_contents ( '/tmp/utf8_func', "yes");
          } else {
            file_put_contents ( '/tmp/utf8_func', "nao");

          };
    $sutf8 =  iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $s);
    file_put_contents ( '/tmp/utf8_iconv' , $sutf8);
    return $sutf8;
};
```

Output of the `/tmp` files:

`utf8_param` - "the string"

`utf8_mbdetect` - empty, 0 bytes

`utf8_other` - 'Ã '

`utf8_func` - 'yes

`utf8_iconv` - empty, 0 bytes

"the string" is coming from the `MariaDB` database with `Spanish` collation, as usual.  `iconv` was working right, but it seems that something went wrong while I'm developing a new program.  The converted string should be passed to a `javascript` `ajax` call.

What's causing this misbehavior of `iconv`?

Comment: What's the misbehavior?

Comment: I get no output from `iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $s);`